# Rails - Cannot disable a button with an option box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this:

```
<%= form_tag do %>

<%= label_tag :name, 'Name: ' %><%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
<%= submit_tag 'submit', disabled: @op %>
<%= label_tag :dis_false, "True" %>
<%= radio_button_tag :dis, :true %><br />
<%= label_tag :dis_true, "False" %>
<%= radio_button_tag :dis, :false %><br />
<% end %>
```

Routes are set up properly and @op = params[:dis].

Now, when I try to select "false" and click "submit", the button becomes disabled. This should only happen if the optin-box "True" is selected. So  I was wondering, what's going on here? I was basically trying to make a simple app that would help me enable/disable a button via an option box.

Comment: are you doing it by javascript? could you show code disable submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get your answer, when you send false `@op` is set to `"false"` not `false`.

Try this:

```
@op = params[:dis] == "true"
```

This is:

```
params[:dis] # comes as a string "true" or "false", since these are values radio button returns.

params[:dis] == "true" # is true without quotes when radio button with value "true"
                       # false, without quotes, otherwise, for example when
                       # when params[:dis] is "false"
```

Comment: Are you saying the the output of params[:anythinggoeshere] is always a string? Btw I also tried @op = eval(params[:dis]) that worked too.

Comment: As far as I have seen, yes. eval is not good in this case, since user could send arbitrary code in param dis.

Comment: Can't quite understand this ? : notation, I know it's if/then shorthand notation, but what does it really mean? Is it called a shorthand notation at all?

Comment: Can be shortened to just `@op = params[:dis] == "true" ` the ternary operator is not necessary

Comment: I appreciate that this worked, but I haven't got the slightest idea why @op = params[:dis] == "true" works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'dis' would be better suited as a checkbox in this case. Disable/enable can also be handled via javascript / coffeescript. Add this to your js.coffee file in app/assets:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#dis").change ->
    $("#submit").attr "disabled", $("#dis").is(":checked")
```

Or in plain jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dis").change(function() {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", $("#dis").is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

And update your form fields:

```
<%= submit_tag 'submit', disabled: @op, :id => "submit" %>
<%= check_box_tag(:dis, '', false) %>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in Rails and not really familiar with jquery/JS so would appreciate Rails-only solution. Thanks.

Comment: For the jquery snippet, you can literally paste this in below your form, wrapped in  <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags.